# Laravel auth attempt receiving a parameter from column table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Here's my `AccountController` class:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) {
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request ['email'], 'password' => $request ['password']]) ) {
        $auth = \Auth::user()->role_id;

        switch($auth){
            case '1': return redirect()->route('admin/index');
            break;
            case '2': return redirect()->route('client/home');
            break;
            case '3': return redirect()->route('messenger/home');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want my `Auth::attempt` method to log on the user if only that specific user's  `confirmation_code` value is `true/1`.

How can I do it? Accepting the specific users confirmation_code in the Auth::attempt function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `confirmation_code` to the array you're passing to `attempt()` method:

```
Auth::attempt([
    'email' => $request['email'],
    'password' => $request['password'],
    'confirmation_code' => true,
]);
```

Laravel's [authentication manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users) clearly states that you can add any arbitrary condition. Quoting:

> If you wish, you also may add extra conditions to the authentication query in addition to the user's e-mail and password. For example, we may verify that user is marked as "active":

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

In case you're curious, here's what happens [under the hood](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php#L98); Notice the `foreach`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
 *
 * @param  array  $credentials
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    if (empty($credentials)) {
        return;
    }

    // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
    // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
    // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
    $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
        if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $query->first();
}
```